# validating union type of number and enum in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am making an SSML builder npm package using Typescript.

I have a function in typescript such as below which convert a Prosody object into an SSML tag.

```
prosody(attributes: ProsodyAttributes, word: string){

        const {rate, volume, pitch} = attributes;

        let tag = `<prosody `;

        if(rate){

            tag += `rate="${rate}"`

        }

        if(pitch){

            tag += `pitch="${pitch}"`

        }

        if(volume){

            tag += `volume="${volume}"`

        }

        tag += `>${this._escape(word)}</prosody>`;

        this._elements.push(tag);

        return this;

    }
```

Following are the types. Rate, Pitch and Volume can either be numbers or a definite value. I have created an enum for each of them. I am using a union type to cater for both numbers as well as the fixed values.

```
enum Rate{
    xslow = "x-slow",
    slow = "slow",
    medium = "medium",
    fast = "fast",
    xfast = "x-fast"
}

enum Pitch{
    xlow = "x-low",
    low = "low",
    medium = "medium",
    high = "high",
    xhigh = "x-high"
}

export enum Volume{
    silent = "silent",
    xsoft = "x-soft",
    soft = "soft",
    medium = "medium",
    loud = "loud",
    xloud = "x-loud"
}

interface ProsodyAttributes {
    rate?: Rate | number,
    pitch?: Pitch | number,
    volume?: Volume | number
}
```

what is the right way to validate the input parameters to the function?

I have tried something like the code below:

```
if (typeof rate === "number"){

  if(rate < 20 || rate > 200){

    throw("attributes.rate is out of range")

  }

} else {

  if(!Object.values(Rate).includes(rate)){

    throw("attributes.rate is invalid");

  }

}
```

I have the following queries:

1. Is this the right approach?
2. Should I be using enums in the first place? Is it overkill?

I have to use this project in a non-typescript project where the values of rate, pitch and volume will be picked from the request parameter?

[image]

My approach to design the prosody function is causing type incompatibility. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Enums get emitted by the typescript compiler. This means they exist at runtime. So from either javascript or typescript you should do:

```
prosody({ volume: Volume.loud })
```

If you use enums that's the way to go. You'll want to avoid passing in the raw value of that enum.

And the way you validate that also seems fine.

---

An alternative that may be simpler is to use a union of strings instead.

Something like:

```
const rates = ["x-slow", "slow", "medium", "fast", "x-fast"] as const
type Rate = (typeof rates)[number] // "x-slow" | "slow" | "medium" | "fast" | "x-fast"

const arg = 'slow'
console.log(rates.includes(arg)) // true
```

Now `Rate` is one of the items from the items from the `rates` array. In typed environments you still get autocomplete (though it is slightly less nice than the enum):

[image: union autocomplete]

In the end this is a matter of opinion, and its up to you how you want your API to be.